# How to require monaco editor by using the <script> tag

Tags: monaco-editor

In the documentation it mentions two primary ways: via **AMD** compliant modules and **ESM**.

Is there a way to do this with using only a plain old `<script>` tag? Not sure if there's currently a distribution build that we can copy in the application and require using the script tag.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this in the examples folder: [samples/browser-script-editor](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/main/samples/browser-script-editor/index.html), but seems so it requires installing the library via `npm install` first.

Comment: Where do you see Node.js being used in this example?

Comment: My bad, what I mean is `npm`. It references the `node_modules` folder in src attribute and normally `npm` comes with `NodeJS`

Answer (score 0):

A [script tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) with a `type="module"` attribute should be able to load an ESM script.